# How do I zip a single element and tuple into one tuple?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, tuples

I have a url dictionary and tuple:

```
url = {'url': 'https://test.com'}
expected = (0, "Test")
```

I need to zip the two objects together into 1 tuple so I can pass it into pytest parametrize as:

```
({'url': 'https://test.com'}, 0, "Test")
```

However my output when I try using `zip(url, expected)` is giving me strange outputs like:

```
('url', 0)
```

Can someone advise how I can do this?  I've tried using `zip(url, *expected)` as well but that did not work either.  Thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
>>> (url, ) + expected
({'url': 'https://test.com'}, 0, 'Test')
```

Comment: Thanks! will this work with zipping a list of single elements and list of tuples as well? For example turning 2 urls and 2 tuples into [(url, 0, "Test'), (url2, 1, "Test")]

Comment: `[(url, ) + expect for url, expect in zip(urls, expected)]` works using your provided answer.  Thanks again